# Does all the Identity Providers (OneLogin, Okta etc) uses the same SAML endpoint of their own?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, onelogin, idp

I'm trying to integrate with OneLogin SAML login. I'm just wondering if each identity provider uses the same SAML endpoint across all users?

My current structure would prefer not to collect any information from the user and instead to redirect to the SAML endpoint based on the user selection on which SAML login they would like to authenticate. So in our database, we will have all the supported IdPs SAML endpoint (assuming each of them is the same), hence there is no need for user's additional information such as email id to retrieve the SAML endpoint if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SAML endpoint you send users to for authentication by their IdP is the same for all users of that IdP. Each IdP will have a different SAML endpoint.

In your database, you'd need to store the SAML entityID (IdP) associated with each user and lookup the SAML endpoint from the SAML metadata for that entityID as, if the metadata changes, the endpoint may change too but the entityID won't normally change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To clarify, so based on your answer, for instance, OneLogin will have the same SAML endpoint for all of their users regardless of which organization their users from?

So instead of storing the SAML endpoint in the database, I should query from the metadata each time for the SAML endpoint when redirecting our users?

Comment: in general and IdP has a single SSO endpoint and it's best to get it from the IdP's metadata as it can change but the metadata will be updated with the new endpoint. I'm not sure what OneLogin do. If they have metadata the SSO endpoint will be in there. If there are multiple endpoints they will be in the metadata

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! One last question, does IdP also has one metadata only? So i can assume all users from that specific IdP should have the same metadata retrieve point.

Comment: Each IdP has its own entityID and each entityID has its own SAML metadata containing details of its security certificates and SSO endpoint. I've never see it but I would assume an IdP could potentially support more than one entityID but again, each would have its own metadata. A user will be associated with a single entityID and therefore a single metadata file. If you know the user's entityID (i.e. the IdP they login at) you can use that to load the metadata for the IdP to find their SSO URL, as long as the metadata for the entityID is up to date. I refresh all entityID metadata once a week.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Very much appreciated!